# How to add where in 3 condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I have some model for searching like this,

```
public function get_products_by_keyword($keyword) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $this->db->like('item_name',$keyword);
    $this->db->where('item_product_type', 'watches');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```

> item_product_type list: watches, building, aksesoris, eyeware, promo

in the database, I have 5 `item_product_type` but I want to show just 3 categories, how to do that in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use where_in to pass three type lists

```
$this->db->where_in('item_product_type', ["watches", "building", "aksesoris"]);
```

Official [doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in).

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::whereIn()

Comment: @Misdan updated my answer, once check and official doc link also

Comment: @Misdan Happy to help *To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in..*

Answer (score 1):

use where_in() function for that ,

```
 $categories = array('watches','building','promo');
 public function get_products_by_keyword($keyword,$categories) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $this->db->like('item_name',$keyword);
    $this->db->where_in('item_product_type', $categories);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use where_in()

```
 $this->db->where_in();
```

Generates a WHERE field IN ('item', 'item') SQL query joined with AND if appropriate

```
$items = array('watches', 'building', 'aksesoris');
$this->db->where_in('item_product_type', $items);
```